# R package calls for library update

Tags: r, monetdblite

So I'm trying to implement some R script that you can see [here](https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/master/Survey%20of%20Income%20and%20Program%20Participation/replicate%20census%20poverty%20statistics.R). I'm using R 3.2.3 on Mac OS 10.10.5.

But an error is stopping me, and it involves a part of the library I'm not familiar with. The problem comes up when I try and load MonetDBLite with the following line:

```
> library(MonetDBLite)
```

At that point, I get a long error, but the gist of it is this:

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: libmonetdb5.so 
requires version 8.0.0 or later, but liblzma.5.dylib 
provides version 6.0.0
```

I tried updating the whole Mac OS system, but that didn't do it. Am I supposed to update liblzma? Any other ideas?

Comment: Sure sounds like it to me. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. The error message says: I need version[y], but only version[x] is available.

Comment: I don't see either a binary or source version of "MonetDBLite" for the Mac using the GUI Install Packages panel, and then going to CRAN I don't see one for any OS. Are you sure that it's not 'mongolite' that you want?

Comment: hi, sorry, we will try to resolve this soon.  if you urgently need to use sipp, you can try it with SQLite using the version history here:  https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/39a82aa32155fd90ed00c3dae9302ab416e2a047  sorry

Comment: Thanks, Anthony! No real rush on the SIPP. But I'm excited about eventually taking a look.

Comment: Ah I think this is due to a recent change in core MonetDB. Will have a look later today.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install xz
```

This installs XZ Utils which has the latest Lempel–Ziv–Markov chain algorithm (LZMA) and will solve the version conflict.

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved by now, try MonetDBLite 0.2.0